# R, httr2 login with pwd and token auth

Tags: r, authentication, httr, auth-token, httr2

I'm trying to use httr2 in R to access an API behind a SSO server. I've been given a way to do it with python and I just can't get beyond the login page in R. This works in python:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# URLs
login_url = "https://auth.ABCDEFG.org/"
app_url = "https://myDestination.ABCDEFG.org/"
api_url = app_url + "api/"

sess = requests.session()
auth_req = sess.get(url=login_url)

# get auth form token
soup = BeautifulSoup(auth_req.text, "html.parser")
auth_form_token = soup.select_one("input#token")["value"]

# get credentials (not shown)
# post credentials plus token
auth_req = sess.post(
    url=login_url,
    data={"user": username, "password": pwd, "token": auth_form_token},
)

# initial GET to acquire csrf token
get_req = sess.get(api_url)
sess.headers["Referer"] = app_url
sess.headers["X-CSRFToken"] = get_req.cookies["csrftoken"]
```

With the approach above, the session authorizes, gives me the CSRF token and lets me request data from the API.

With httr2 I there's no "session" (but help suggests that's ok as cookies are cached).

There also doesn't seem to be a way to pass user/pwd credentials *and* the auth_token. I've tried adding it as `auth_bearer_token` but that seems to replace the user/pwd settings (not amend/append).

I've tried various version of POST from both `httr` and `httr2` and none seem to give me a successful login.

Here's my best attempt:

```
library(rvest)
library(httr2)

# URLs
login_url = "https://auth.ABCDEFG.org/"
app_url = "https://myDestination.ABCDEFG.org/"
api_url = app_url + "api/"

auth_page_data <- read_html(login_url)

# a hack, but it gets me the same token as in the python, above. 
auth_form_token <- auth_page_data %>% html_elements("input") %>% 
  html_attrs() %>% # get list of attributes
  .[[which(lapply(., '[', "id") =='token')]] %>% # get token line from list
  .["value"] # get token value

# get credentials (username, pwd), not shown

# login
req <- request(login_url) %>% 
    req_auth_basic(username, pwd) %>%
    req_auth_bearer_token(auth_form_token)

resp <- req %>% req_perform()

# > resp
# <httr2_response>
# GET https://auth.ABCDEFG.org/
# Status: 200 OK
# Content-Type: text/html
# Body: In memory (5436 bytes)

# > resp_headers(resp)
# <httr2_headers>
#   server: nginx/1.18.0
# date: Mon, 03 Jul 2023 16:38:49 GMT
# content-type: text/html
# x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
# x-content-type-options: nosniff
# cache-control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
# pragma: no-cache
# expires: 0
# access-control-allow-origin: *
#   access-control-allow-credentials: true
# access-control-allow-headers: *
#   access-control-allow-methods: POST,GET
# access-control-expose-headers: *
#   access-control-max-age: 86400
# x-frame-options: DENY
# content-security-policy: default-src 'self';img-src 'self' data:;style-src 'self';font-src 'self';connect-src 'self';script-src 'self';form-action *;frame-ancestors 'none';
# content-encoding: gzip
```

That final response gives `Status OK`, but the headers and body suggest to me that it's just bringing the login page again (e.g. the login failed).

I've been trying to figure this out for a few days now but it's really got me stumped.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Hi Tim did you solve this?

Comment: @stat Sorry, didn't see your comment. I got it working using a `session` in httr and mimicking the python session. I still can't figure it out using only httr2